# PhraseQuery: are the terms strictly searched in their order?

Tags: java, lucene

Are terms searched with a PhraseQuery in Lucene, strictly matched in their order in the sentence ?

For example, if I have "A B C" and the doc contains "A C B", is PhraseQuery returning a hit ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, order matters.  So in your example, the query "A B C" would NOT match a doc containing "A C B".

Comment: Ok, so do you suggest me to parse the strings and concatenate TermQueries with field and term ?

Answer (score 1):

Not if you use [slop](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html#setSlop%28int%29) in your PhraseQuery.

> Sets the number of other words permitted between words in query
>   phrase. If zero, then this is an exact phrase search. For larger
>   values this works like a WITHIN or NEAR operator.
>
> The slop is in fact an edit-distance, where the units correspond to
>   moves of terms in the query phrase out of position. For example, to
>   switch the order of two words requires two moves (the first move
>   places the words atop one another), so to permit re-orderings of
>   phrases, the slop must be at least two.
>
> More exact matches are scored higher than sloppier matches, thus
>   search results are sorted by exactness.
>
> The slop is zero by default, requiring exact matches.